# How to get specified rows from the returns of CimInstance type in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to get specified rows from a `CimInstance` object and I thought to turn them to string, but did not find the answer how to do that.

```
PS C:\Users\laptop> Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightness


Active            : True
CurrentBrightness : 50
InstanceName      : DISPLAY\LEN40A1\4&342c5d56&0&UID67568640_0
Level             : {0, 1, 2, 3...}
Levels            : 101
PSComputerName    :
```

I need to get two rows, "CurrentBrightness : 50" and "Levels  : 101", from the results on screen, but the return is a `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]`. I had tried to make them to be strings though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rows" you see are actually the properties of an object displayed in list form. You can select properties of any given object via the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet:

```
Get-CimInstance ... | Select-Object CurrentBrightness, Levels
```